# Numeric Validation is not working with Samsung Tablet

Tags: javascript

Hi I have applied numeric validation, but it is not working with Samsung tablet.
while working in almost every device and browsers.

```
$("#routingNum").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

We have to check before button click, It should not allow any character except digit.

Comment: `var keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;` and then use `keyCode` variable instead of `e.which`.

Comment: It is still not working with samsung tablet device.

Comment: What error do you get on Tablet?

Answer (score 0):

A quicker solution is to use a input with type number:

```
<input id="routingNumber" type="number" />
```

For debugging, print the value returned by `e.which` on the page.

Comment: if I use type="number" how can we use maxlength.

Comment: @user1078749 You can use `max`, which allows you to set the largest number. So for `maxlength=5` you can use `max=99999`.

Comment: Yes, I am agree, but if you give 99999999 then it will allow it and on click of button, It will check that it is invalid, But I need to check before button click, I mean on keypress. I mean I should not allow more than 5 digits any time.